# Do I have to create separate UIs for Android and iOS with React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to build a mobile app for Android and iOS and think about using React Native.

There is one thing I yet couldn't figure out: Do I have to create separate UIs for Android and iOS or is there some abstraction like in Xamarin.Forms? E.g. can I just say "give me a button" and on Android I get a native Android button and on iOS a native iOS Button or do I have to create separate View layers for Android and iOS (like Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you don't need to create separate UI for both platforms. React Native comes with a few Android and iOS specific components such as `ProgressBarAndroid` and `ProgressViewIOS`. For your button example, there is a simple component called `Button` which renders platform-native buttons that you can also customize if needed.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I don't completely understand "React Native comes with a **few** Android and iOS specific components" - can you explain the few? Aren't all native UI components mapped to React Native?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Yes the vast majority of them are. For example, `Picker`, `ActivityIndicator` and `Image` will render the platform-native view.

I was simply saying in very few cases, they are split into 2 separate components such as [ProgressBarAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/progressbarandroid) and [ProgressViewIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/progressviewios).